# Avoid XSS vulnerability in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, security, xss

My question is very much straight forward, I would like to know how I can restrict user to enter `<script>` tags or any other potential content in the text box control of my C# winform.

I know how to do this in web application, but I am not aware of doing this in C# winforms.

Let me explain my scenario, I have a desktop application where user enter some comments from a textbox which I will store in my db, and the same user can see his comments in a website. So if user enters `window.open("http://www.foo.com")` in comments from desktop application then when I retrieve such comments in website, it will automatically redirect to that site, which I don't want to happen.

Any idea of how to start would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you need to prevent XSS attacks in a desktop application? XSS is a web threat...

Comment: Very strange question, there's no scripting in Winforms.  Your program can only do what you programmed it to do, no option to inject code.  Using a Label instead of a TextBox is an obvious approach.

Comment: Even though it is a desktop application all the data user entered will be stored into the Server DB and he can see the same data from browser through some valid login, so for example if I enter alert("XSS") from desktop textbox I get that in the browser when I retrieve content, I don't want this to be happened.

Answer (score 2):

You write the data as-is in the database and escape it properly when displaying. On a Windows Form you can just display the data, on a HTML page you'll want to encode the HTML entities present in the input, for example through [`HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent that the user enters specific letters into a textbox (i.e. because you're going to store the entered data in an XML file), you have to code this yourself. Implement a handler for the `Validating` event of the textbox and check that the text doesn't contain any illegal characters or strings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,so that means, I need to do the same for all the textboxes in my project?

Comment: Basically yes, but you can obviously use a common function for that (when the same restriction applies to all text boxes). If they're on the same form, you can even connect all boxes to the same event handler.

Comment: Black listing is rarely good practice for security. If it is a comments form and you restrict input you are also restricting functionality.